# xmlstarlet: How do I omit elements with a specific attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I would like to retrieve certain XML elements but only if they do not contain a specific attribute with starlet.

Here is an XML example in file *myFile.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
        <classInfo>
                <subjects>
                        <subject id="1" type="someType">
                                <subjectname>Foo1</subjectname>
                        </subject>
                        <subject id="2" subtype="someSubtype" type="someType">
                                <subjectname>Foo2</subjectname>
                        </subject>
                </subjects>
        </classInfo>
</document>
```

Now, all elements without subtype shall be considered further while all elements with a subtype  (any subtype) shall be ignored.

So far, there is only the xmlstarlet selection considering all elements:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//subject[@type='someType']" -v '@id' -o $'\t' -v 'subjectname[text()]' -nl myFile.xml
```

This results in

1     Foo1

2     Foo2

But the desired outcome is

1     Foo1

In which way has this selection to be enhanced to omit every *subject* with a *subtype*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the predicate `[not(@subtype)]` to your match...

```
-m "//subject[@type='someType'][not(@subtype)]"
```